# change view size relative to anchor point

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to enable user of scaling images from edges ( touch the edge then drag it )
I've been looking around for a way to change the view size dynamically using LayoutParams while keeping the view position anchored to a specific edge.

```
fun View.setSize(width: Int, height: Int) {
val layoutP = layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
layoutP.width = width
layoutP.height = height
layoutParams = layoutP
requestLayout()}
```

The default behaviour when trying the code above is changing the view width and height while keeping the centre point as its.
I tried to set the desired x,y after changing width and height but this resulted in vibrated behaviour going to centre then my new x,y

I'm looking for the same effect as setting pivotY and pivotX on scaling animation.

Comment: I think you should try to use scale animation while performing the drag and only modify layout params when touch is done. Redoing layout every frame is too expensive to be smooth.

Comment: I actually do that but the main problem still exists when the touch is done the vibration happens ( resizing moves the view to center then I move it back to be anchored)

Answer (score 0):

I can just put this reference due the fact i never used this, but i think the documentation it's pretty clear about this:

https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale